# Proof of Riesz-Fischer Theorem using the completeness of $L^1$ to infer completeness of $L^p$.

Tags: lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, banach-spaces

One can infer the completeness of $L^p$ by using the homeomorphism $\varphi: L^p \to L^1$ defined by $f \mapsto |f|^{p-1} f$. This rests on the inequality:
$$ 2^{1-p} || f- g||_p^p \leq ||\varphi(f) -\varphi(g)||_1\leq p  (||f||_p + ||g||_p)^{p-1} ||f-g ||_p$$
Which I am not sure how to prove, does anyone know where this inequality comes from or have any hints on how to show this?
Thanks.

Comment: I suppose the first follows from:
$$2^{1-p}|a-b|^p \leq |a|a|^{p-1} - b|b|^{p-1}|$$ for $a, b \geq 0$, which looks like a Holder inequality (see the exercises of the first chapter in Grafakos' Classical Fourier Analysis, for similar looking, but simpler, inequalities: in particular the $2^{1-p}$ is familiar from these problems), but one could conceivably show by fixing $a$ and thinking of it as a function of $b$ and showing that the function $f_a(b) = |a|a|^{p-1} - b|b|^{p-1}| - 2^{1-p}|a-b|^p \geq 0$, for which it might be useful to break it up into cases to remove the absolute value signs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For the first inequality:**

First we prove that $u^{p}-1-2^{1-p}(u-1)^{p}\geq 0$ for $u\geq 1$.

Let $\phi(u)=u^{p}-1-2^{1-p}(u-1)^{p}$. For $u>1$, then $\phi(u)=\phi(u)-\phi(1)=p(\xi^{p-1}-2^{1-p}(\xi-1)^{p-1})$, where $\xi\in(1,u)$. Note that 
\begin{align*}
\xi^{p-1}&> 2^{1-p}(\xi-1)^{p-1}\\
\xi&> 2^{-1}(\xi-1)\\
2\xi&>\xi-1\\
\xi&>-1
\end{align*}
each step is valid if and only if, so $\xi^{p-1}-2^{1-p}(\xi-1)^{p-1}>0$ and hence $\phi(u)>0$ for $u>1$, and hence $\phi(u)\geq 0$ for $u\geq 1$.

Now let $a\geq b>0$, then $a/b\geq 1$ and hence
\begin{align*}
2^{1-p}\left(\dfrac{a}{b}-1\right)^{p}\leq\left(\dfrac{a}{b}\right)^{p}-1,
\end{align*} 
so
\begin{align*}
2^{1-p}(a-b)^{p}\leq a^{p}-b^{p},
\end{align*}
this inequality also holds for $b=0$, so we conclude that $2^{1-p}(a-b)^{p}\leq a^{p}-b^{p}$ for $a\geq b\geq 0$.

Assume now that $a\geq 0\geq b$, by Jensen's inequality,
\begin{align*}
\left(\dfrac{a+(-b)}{2}\right)^{p}\leq\dfrac{1}{2}a^{p}+\dfrac{1}{2}(-b)^{p},
\end{align*}
we conclude that
\begin{align*}
2^{1-p}(a-b)^{p}\leq a^{p}+(-b)^{p}=\bigg|a|a|^{p-1}-b|b|^{p-1}\bigg|.
\end{align*}
We conclude the general inequality that
\begin{align*}
2^{1-p}|f-g|^{p}\leq\bigg|f|f|^{p-1}-g|g|^{p-1}\bigg|,
\end{align*}
taking integrals both sides, we have
\begin{align*}
2^{1-p}\|f-g\|_{p}^{p}&=2^{1-p}\int|f-g|^{p}\\
&\leq\int\bigg|f|f|^{p-1}-g|g|^{p-1}\bigg|\\
&=\|\varphi(f)-\varphi(g)\|_{1}.
\end{align*}

**For the second inequality:**

For $a,b\geq 0$, then $|a^{p}-b^{p}|=p|a-b|\xi^{p-1}\leq p|a-b|(a+b)^{p-1}$ for some $\xi$ lies in between $a,b$, this is by Mean Value Theorem.

Assume first that $f,g\geq 0$, then 
\begin{align*}
|f^{p}-g^{p}|\leq p|f-g|(f+g)^{p-1},
\end{align*}
then by Holder's inequality, we have 
\begin{align*}
\int|f^{p}-g^{p}|&\leq p\left(\int|f-g|^{p}\right)^{1/p}\left(\int((f+g)^{p-1})^{p/(p-1)}\right)^{(p-1)/p}\\
&=p\|f-g\|_{p}\|f+g\|_{p}^{p-1}\\
&\leq p\|f-g\|_{p}(\|f\|_{p}+\|g\|_{p})^{p-1},
\end{align*}
where the last inequality is by Minkowski's inequality.

Now consider the general $f,g$. If $x$ is such that $f(x),g(x)\geq 0$, then 
\begin{align*}
||f(x)|^{p-1}f(x)-|g(x)|^{p-1}g(x)|&=|f(x)^{p}-g(x)^{p}|\leq p|f(x)-g(x)|(|f(x)|+|g(x)|)^{p-1},
\end{align*}
if $x$ is such that $f(x)\geq 0\geq g(x)$, then
\begin{align*}
||f(x)|^{p-1}f(x)-|g(x)|^{p-1}g(x)|&=f(x)^{p}+(-g(x))^{p}\\
&\leq(f(x)-g(x))^{p}\\
&\leq p(f(x)-g(x))(f(x)-g(x))^{p-1}\\
&=p|f(x)-g(x)|(|f(x)|+|g(x)|)^{p-1},
\end{align*}
so in either case, we have the inequality that
\begin{align*}
||f|^{p-1}f-|g|^{p-1}g|\leq p|f-g|(|f|+|g|)^{p-1},
\end{align*}
the rest reasoning is similar to the first one by taking Holder's inequality and then Minkowski's inequality.