# Useful but not well known inequality

Tags: inequality, absolute-value

At some point, I was looking in this forum for some useful inequality concerning absolute values. I found a very nice one, slightly simple to prove, but didn't find any formal proof of it, so I am using this question to write one here.

*For every $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ and any $p\geq 1$, the following inequality holds
\begin{equation}
    2^{1-p}|x-y|^p \leq |x|x|^{p-1}-y|y|^{p-1}|.
\end{equation}*

Context:

- I found first this inequality here: [Difference of powers inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/327242/difference-of-powers-inequality) , where they called it ''Mazur's inequality"
- In this other post [Difference of powers inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/327242/difference-of-powers-inequality) , someone cited these two places as a reference for this inequality, but they are only accesible in Chinese: https://www.zhihu.com/question/474094278/answer/2015826434 , https://www.doc88.com/p-096371580918.html (Page 135, (3rd Ed.))
- This other question [Inequality for difference of powers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2881415/inequality-for-difference-of-powers) , suggested some hints for the proof.

Comment: Look at the answer to this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2665581/proof-of-riesz-fischer-theorem-using-the-completeness-of-l1-to-infer-complete?noredirect=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that since $p\geq 1$, the function $f: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by
\begin{equation*}
    f(x)=|x|^p
\end{equation*}
is convex and continuous. In particular this implies that $f$ is mid-point convex (see [Midpoint-Convex and Continuous Implies Convex](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83383/midpoint-convex-and-continuous-implies-convex)), this is: for every $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ we have
\begin{equation}\label{midpoint}
    f\left( \frac{x+y}{2}\right)\leq \frac{f(x)+f(y)}{2}.
\end{equation}
We assume in this proof that $x\geq y$. This is not restrictive at all, since the proof in the case $y>x$ works analogous. We have then three different cases to consider.

- If $x\geq y \geq 0$: we write $\delta=x-y\geq0$ and then it is well known that
  \begin{equation*}
      \delta^p+y^p\leq (y+\delta)^p,
  \end{equation*}
  from where we get
  \begin{equation}\label{ineq1}
      (x-y)^p \leq x^p-y^p\leq 2^{p-1}(x^p-y^p),
  \end{equation}
  where the last inequality follows since $p\geq 1$. Now is just a matter of rewriting this and we obtain the statement.
- If $x\geq 0 \geq y$, then we can just write $\tilde{y}=-y>0$, and by the mid-point convexity we get
  \begin{equation*}
       \frac{|x-y|^p}{2^p}=\frac{|x+\tilde{y}|^p}{2^p}\leq \frac{|x|^p+|\tilde{y}|^p}{2}=\frac{x|x|^{p-1}-y|y|^{p-1}}{2},
  \end{equation*}
  obtaining the result.
- The case $0\geq x\geq y$ is covered when $y\geq x\geq0$.